# How to use win32print in an OpenERP module?

Tags: python, odoo

I try to use a Bixolon receipt printer with OE on Windows 7. I success to print directly from a small python module using win32print (coming with py32win) with the code below :

win32print is not natively in OE so I paste win32print.pyd in OE server directory and put the code in a wizard of my OE module.
 I can see my wizard, launch it without error but then nothing happens  : no print, no error message.

Any ideas ?
Thank you

```
import win32print

printer=OpenPrinter(win32print.GetDefaultPrinter())
hJob = win32print.StartDocPrinter (printer, 1, ("RVGI Print", None, "RAW"))
g=open('test3.txt','r')
raw_data = bytes ( open( 'test3.txt' , 'r').read ())
try:
    win32print.StartPagePrinter (printer)
    win32print.WritePrinter (printer, raw_data)
    win32print.EndPagePrinter (printer)
finally:
    win32print.EndDocPrinter (printer)
win32print.ClosePrinter (printer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the python code runs on the server. Is your printer connected to the server?

Also, you don't have an `except` section in your `try`. That makes errors go by silently. Try removing the `try` block so that errors are raised. Looking at them you might figure out the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your advices. The printer is directly connected to the test server. I removed the try block and no errors in the server log file.Do I have to look elsewhere  ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if you typed here incorrectly, but the way you imported the `win32print` module force you to attach it to module function calls and you haven't done this in your first line:

```
printer = OpenPrinter(win32print.GetDefaultPrinter())
```

should be

```
printer = win32print.OpenPrinter(win32print.GetDefaultPrinter())
```

And there is another point that I don't really understands, but [Tim Golden](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html) put in his tutorial and could be your problem:

```
raw_data = bytes('your_text')
```

could be just:

```
raw_data = 'your_text'
```

depending on your system version. You also haven't specified the encoding, but since you got no errors that may not be the problem.

For the version thing Tim Golden posted:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info >= (3,):
  raw_data = bytes ("This is a test", "utf-8")
else:
  raw_data = "This is a test"
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for the help and the link to Tim Golden. I finally had to change the OS to Ubuntu (OE on a standalone win 7 was really too slow). No specific cups driver was avalailable for this Bixolon (depsite the fact it was announced on their website)) but I succeed to print the receipts with some "brutal" commands ;)